# dynamic space between footer and div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a certain amount of space between the top of my footer and a div.

Right now each page is of a different size and I'm adjusting this manually. The biggest issues I'm having is across different formats of web browsers my manual space is changing. and on a couple pages I have a js questionnaire, when the questionnaire is completed my div slides down over top of my back and next buttons. I corrected this by creating a new CSS style for it.
Is there a way I can set my div (Which is a box with text) to align on every page the same distance from the footer and on every browser. Right now my code is only working correctly in IE9.

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```css
#mainInfoBox
{

margin-bottom:-35px; !important;    
clear:both;
min-height:2em;
height: auto !important;
height:32px;
padding: 2px 3px 0 3px;
border: 1px solid #4c6352;
background-color:#f2f684;
color:#000;
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
text-align:center; 
display:block;
position: relative;
}
```

And this is what I'm using in the html, though that values change on every page:

```
<div id="mainInfoBox" style="margin-top:193px; clear:both">Blah Blah Blah</div>
```

Comment: have you reset your CSS? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Sounds like you use some absolute position somewhere or set heights where min-height would be more efficient ? Can you produce a single page in jsfiddle, so we see how you manage the main layout ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to share the main code I'm using, it's proprietary. Most of the layout is designed in js and is locked down. I'm thinking there has to be a fairly basic way of keeping my div about 10px give or take off of the top of the footer

Comment: Properietary or not, once you launch your website everyone can view the source and css code for your website... Regardless, we still need to see more code

Comment: Well, that's just it. The only people that will see the code is part of that proprietary group. So really no one outside of the company that I'm building this for and the company that actually built the template will see the website. It'll be all intranet. Well thanks for the help, maybe I'll have to go to the guy that built the template and see if he can fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your footer is the same on every page, you can set a fixed height, or at least calculate the height of it. Then absolutely position the div you want on top of it using the bottom property like so:

```css
footer { height: 250px; }
#mainInfoBox { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 260px; /* so it is 10px on top of the footer */
}
```